# Time-out a request based on input value of request field in DataPower

Tags: xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

I have a Soap request and in that I have field called phone number. If the phone number value ends with '8' then the request should time out and not send any response back.

More information : I have a Loop back Multi-protocol gateway and not doing any complex transformations. Depending upon the last digit of phone number I am forming the Soap response message.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

you can use Conditional action, write xpath there to send(reject) to Error Rule.

Comment: Hi Anil,
 I don't want any response to be sent back. The request should time out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call something that takes time to process. Just looping a template would build CPU strain. If you are on Firmware 7.1 or higher you can add a GWS with a setTimeout() function that simply waits longer than the timeout. 
If you are on 7.5 you can just call the GWS from XSLT else add the GWS in a loop-back xml firewall that you call from a url-open() in the Xslt.

Another option might be to raise the timeout of the url-ooen() and call a dummy (=non existing) url.

Comment: facebook? you mean "Firmware version"?